# VS2015 - Issue to push generated package - Symbol

Tags: symbols, symbol-server

after we install VS2015 in our server our symbol packages are getting this error when we try to push then to the symbols server:
 (506) Package submission failed: Unknown custom metadata item kind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a reason for it, then I create another csproj from scratch, then it worked partialy.

When the PDB is added to the package it fails when I try to push the package to the symbol source.

The problem here was the MSBuild 14 with the pdb metadata. There is a fix for it in this [link.](https://github.com/SymbolSource/SymbolSource.Community/issues/32)